# How to click a button using using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on a button located in the extreme right corner of the page, which has multiple classes.

**Sample Image of the HTML code**
[image: Sample Image]

**This is how it should open a search box for the use to enter a string**
[image: This is how it should open a search box for the use to enter a string]

**What I have done so far**
[image: What I have done so far]

This is the error msg:

Error occurred while adding the label: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".label-bar_addLabel.FZmV6 button"}
(Session info: MicrosoftEdge=115.0.1901.188); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF69CC45432+69586]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF69CBD5672+760242]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF69C98B8CC]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF69C9D2C79]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF69C9D2D8A]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF69CA0F007]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF69C9F2DEF]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF69C9C6A11]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF69CA0C241]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF69C9F2B83]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF69C9C589E]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF69C9C4B6B]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF69C9C6024]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogManager::DispatchEventBroadcast [0x00007FF69CE1D239+1294553]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF69CA449F4]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF69CB23DF1+33073]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF69CB1C409+1865]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogManager::DispatchEventBroadcast [0x00007FF69CE1BE11+1289393]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogConfiguration::operator* [0x00007FF69CBDDC78+20184]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogConfiguration::operator* [0x00007FF69CBDA304+5476]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogConfiguration::operator* [0x00007FF69CBDA3FC+5724]
Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF69CBCECB1+733169]
BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFFF2505590+16]
RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFFF2E0485B+43]

Process finished with exit code 0

---

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

use [SelectorGadget chrome extention](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/selectorgadget/mhjhnkcfbdhnjickkkdbjoemdmbfginb) to simply find CSS Selector of any elements by clicking on it.

[image of how it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxY21.png)

it also provide xpath of element which can be used in selenium in case of css selector continue to fail.

this is sample code for find an element by xpath in selenium:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "replace with your xpath")
```

Comment: Not my downvote. The comment is to highlight your answer was in the "low quality answers" queue. Your edit has cleared it from the queue now. However I cannot help with the down vote.